# How to use countif based on a custom number format

Tags: excel

I have a cell(B1) on my sheet that has a custom format: > 0,' K' which shows as >500 K once I input 500000.

I am trying to use that cell on my countif formula to show the number of rows that pass this criterion but it's not working for some reason:

=countif(B2:B,B1)

Is there a workaround for this without hardcoding ">B1" on my formula?

Comment: The value stored in B1 does not change with a change in format. So, no, unless you want to resort to VBA..

Comment: Try `=countif(B2:B,">"&B1)`